# Why does running Spark application using "sbt run" fail in sbt 1.0.x?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, apache-spark-sql

I have a simple Spark project which I try to run with `sbt run`. However it results in an exception during codegen:

```
17/12/13 15:19:27 ERROR CodeGenerator: failed to compile: org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java', Line 15, Column 34: Cannot determine simple type name "scala"
/* 001 */ public Object generate(Object[] references) {
/* 002 */   return new GeneratedIterator(references);
/* 003 */ }
/* 004 */
/* 005 */ final class GeneratedIterator extends org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator {
/* 006 */   private Object[] references;
/* 007 */   private scala.collection.Iterator[] inputs;
/* 008 */   private org.apache.spark.sql.execution.metric.SQLMetric scan_numOutputRows;
/* 009 */   private scala.collection.Iterator scan_input;
/* 010 */
/* 011 */   public GeneratedIterator(Object[] references) {
/* 012 */     this.references = references;
/* 013 */   }
/* 014 */
/* 015 */   public void init(int index, scala.collection.Iterator[] inputs) {
/* 016 */     partitionIndex = index;
/* 017 */     this.inputs = inputs;
/* 018 */     this.scan_numOutputRows = (org.apache.spark.sql.execution.metric.SQLMetric) references[0];
/* 019 */     scan_input = inputs[0];
/* 020 */
/* 021 */   }
/* 022 */
/* 023 */   protected void processNext() throws java.io.IOException {
/* 024 */     while (scan_input.hasNext()) {
/* 025 */       InternalRow scan_row = (InternalRow) scan_input.next();
/* 026 */       scan_numOutputRows.add(1);
/* 027 */       append(scan_row);
/* 028 */       if (shouldStop()) return;
/* 029 */     }
/* 030 */   }
/* 031 */ }

org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java', Line 15, Column 34: Cannot determine simple type name "scala"
```

This doesn't happen with `spark-submit`. Build definitions is minimal:

```
name := "untitled"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.2.1"
)
```

so is the code (I'll post it, it someone thinks it is relevant, but I believe that the problem is generic) and `build.properties`:

```
sbt.version = 1.0.4
```

As far as I understand this happens because Spark cannot find Scala libraries on runtime - is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've recently noticed that using sbt 1.0.x breaks *somehow* execution of Spark applications via `sbt run`.

My guess is that the root cause could be Scala 2.12.x that sbt 1.0.x uses under the covers that *somehow* triggers the issue.

Until the issue is sorted out, I recommend running Spark applications using `spark-submit`.

Comment: it might also have to do with the bgrun changes in sbt 1, it's a pretty fundamental change to what `sbt run` does